# Sum with more indices

Tags: definition

I have trouble understanding this way of writing a sum. How can I interpret the sum with indices $1\leq i_1<...< i_r\leq n$ ?$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right|=\sum_{r=1}^n(-1)^{r-1}\sum_{1\le i_1<\cdots<i_r\le n}\left|\bigcap_{j=1}^rA_{i_j}\right|$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 0):

This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for the union of $n$ sets.

The inner sum over the $i_j$ indicates choosing all values for such indices satisfying the given inequality. So, for one choice or $r$, we sum the sizes of all $\binom{n}{r}$ intersections of $r$ sets out of the $n$.

The outer sum causes the final result to be the odd-$r$ results minus the even-$r$ results.

Let's consider the $n=2$ case as an example, with contributions from $r=1$ and $r=2$, the latter given a $-$ sign. With $r=1$, the inequality simplifies to $1\le i_1\le2$, so the contribution is $\sum_{i=1}^2|A_i|=|A_1|+|A_2|$ if we rename $i_1$ as $i$ so $i\in\{1,\,2\}$. With $r=2$, the inequality simplifies to $1\le i_1<i_2\le2$, so the contribution is $-\sum_{i<j}|A_i\cap A_j|=-|A_1\cap A_2|$ if we rename $i_1,\,i_2$ as $i,\,j$ respectively so $i=1,\,j=2$. The $n=2$ case is then the famous result$$\left|A_1\cup A_2\right|=|A_1|+|A_2|-|A_1\cap A_2|.$$Similarly, the $n=3$ case is$$\begin{align}|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|&=|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|\\&-|A_1\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_3|-|A_2\cap A_3|\\&+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem is that i dont know what sum i would get with the inner sum because i never worked with that kind of  indices for a sum and i also dont know about the Aij indices. is the inner sum the same as for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++) in a programming language? can you please write me the sum for n=2 with the indices for i and j in Aij?

Comment: @akana See edit.

Answer (score 0):

At     first    we   look at  some special  cases, to become more familiar with  the notation.   Then we  look  at  the  general case.

**$r=1$:**
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leq i_1\leq n} f(i_1)&=\sum_{i_1=1}^n f(i_1)\\
\end{align*}

**$r=2$:**
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2\leq n} f(i_1,i_2)&=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n-1}\,\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^n f(i_1,i_2)\\
&=\sum_{i_2=2}^n\,\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2-1}f(i_1,i_2)
\end{align*}

**$r=3$:**
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<i_3\leq n} f(i_1,i_2,i_3)&=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n-2}\,\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{n-1}\,\sum_{i_3=i_2+1}^{n} f(i_1,i_2,i_3)\\
&=\sum_{i_3=3}^n\,\sum_{i_2=2}^{i_3-1}\,\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2-1}f(i_1,i_2,i_3)
\end{align*}

> **General $r$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n} f(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r)}&=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n-(r-1)}\,\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{n-(r-2)}\cdots\sum_{i_r=i_{r-1}+1}^{n} f(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r)\\
> &=\sum_{i_r=r}^n\,\sum_{i_{r-1}=r-1}^{i_r-1}\cdots\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2-1}f(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r)
> \end{align*}